# Weblogic server startup profiling tools

Tags: weblogic, profiling, visualvm, jprofiler, yourkit

What would be the best tool or approach if I want to profile my weblogic startup and tune start-up timing.

Can it be done by visual vm or jprofiler or yourkit? What would be the best?

Answer (score 0):

If you use JProfiler, use the integration wizard for Weblogic to configure profiling by selecting `Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration` from the main menu.

On the "Startup mode" step, select the "Wait for a connection from the JProfiler GUI" option.

[image]

When you start the session, the "Session Startup" dialog is shown. Select an initial recording profile with the recordings that you are interested in.

[image]