# server startup profiling (to reduce time by analysing data)

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, profiling, visualvm, jprofiler

I am facing a problem and could not find solutions anywhere. The thing is I need to profile weblogic server startup for my application and get data. later we will try to reduce the time.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: You can first take several thread dumps when WebLogic is starting. It will help you  to know where it is spending its time. You can do this with JConsole.

Comment: You asked the same question 3 days ago and I already answered it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934993/weblogic-server-startup-profiling-tools